# Saving contents of shopping cart to database (PHP/SQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I'm currently creating a simple e-commerce website in PHP using sql database. Website has a shopping basket with a view_cart page, where contents of the shopping basket are displayed, ordered items with subtotal for postage and all can be seen.
 Now what I am trying to do is to save the order details to the sql database and redirect user to a page that confirms purchase. I've tried to implement it myself using button that runs a script with a query but no luck so far. Database contains three rows, `transaction_ID (AI)` and two rows for data from basket (ID and total). Anybody could help me with this issue? I'm completely stuck at this moment.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
<div class="cart-view-table-back">
    <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
    <table width="100%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th><th>Remove</th></tr></thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        include("auth.php");
        include_once("config.php");
        require('db.php');
        if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) //check session var
        {
            $total = 0; //set initial total value
            $b = 0; //var for zebra stripe table 
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
            {
                //set variables to use in content below
                $title = $cart_itm["title"];
                $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
                $price = $cart_itm["price"];
                $id = $cart_itm["id"];
                $product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
                $subtotal = ($price * $product_qty); //calculate Price x Qty

                $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; //class for zebra stripe 
                echo '<tr class="'.$bg_color.'">';
                echo '<td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$id.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$currency.$price.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$currency.$subtotal.'</td>';
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$id.'" /></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                $total = ($total + $subtotal); //add subtotal to total var
            }

            $grand_total = $total + $shipping_cost; //grand total including shipping cost
            foreach($taxes as $key => $value){ //list and calculate all taxes in array
                    $tax_amount     = round($total * ($value / 100));
                    $tax_item[$key] = $tax_amount;
                    $grand_total    = $grand_total + $tax_amount;  //add tax val to grand total
            }

            $list_tax       = '';
            foreach($tax_item as $key => $value){ //List all taxes
                $list_tax .= $key. ' : '. $currency. sprintf("%01.2f", $value).'<br />';
            }
            $shipping_cost = ($shipping_cost)?'Shipping Cost : '.$currency. sprintf("%01.2f", $shipping_cost).'<br />':'';
        }
        ?>
        <tr><td colspan="5"><span style="float:right;text-align: right;"><?php echo $shipping_cost. $list_tax; ?>Amount Payable : <?php echo sprintf("%01.2f", $grand_total);?></span></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
        echo "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">Add More Items</a>";
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php 
    $current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    echo $current_url; ?>" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: And where is the code here that add the information to your DB?

Comment: I was going to use a button with POST method , and so it's using the variables from the shopping cart $ID and $total to add them to database      <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $SQL = "INSERT INTO orders (id, total) VALUES ('$id','$total')";
     $result = mysql_query($SQL);
}
?>

Comment: Whats your problem i cant understand? You cant redirect user or what?

Comment: records are not added to the table using this method and I'm unsure why, I am quite new to php and sql so I wanted to ensure the code is correct